# Apple Watch: deep linking after notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch, ios8.3

When I receive a notification on my watch that was set by my application I want to deep link into my apple watch app.

**Currently what happens:**

- A notification occurs on the watch
- We click on our action "Add Notes"
- Our app opens up to the add note screen
- A note is added
- The application closes and returns to where it was before the notification started.

Is there a way to keep the app open after the actions ends? If not is there apple documentation explaining why this is not the control flow?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement deep linking, or how to close the app after you're done with the flow?

Comment: I want to know how to keep the app open after the flow

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're asking how to implement deep linking into your WatchKit app.

Many people don't realize, if you're using a dynamic notification interface, you can do it using Handoff. Simply broadcast a user activity the Watch is registered to handle in your notification controller, like so:

```
[self updateUserActivity:@"com.briangilham.ExampleApp.readingArticle"
            userInfo:@{@"articleID":@"1234567890"}
          webpageURL:nil];
```

If you don't want the user's iPhone to attempt to continue the activity, I'd recommend using an activity string the host app doesn't recognize.

Then, in your WatchKit app's initial interface controller, you can implement [`handleUserActivity:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/handleUserActivity:) and load the note creation interface.

Comment: I would love to know why it closes the application after the call. However, if I can't figure that out using handoff to keep the app alive is just as good.